# How to prevent lines skipped with <span> and <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use a code for a countdown, which works but I don't like how it displays (in red)

As you can see, it displays on 8 lines, I would like one

[image]

By so I understand with the code, it is because of this section:

```
Plus que <strong><font color="#ff0000">
<div id="clockdiv">
<span class="days"></span><div class="smalltext">jours</div>
<span class="hours"></span><div class="smalltext">hrs</div>
<span class="minutes"></span><div class="smalltext">mins</div>
<span class="seconds"></span><div class="smalltext">secs</div>
</font></strong> pour profiter de la promotion !
</div>
```

But "div" and "span" should not force the text to the next line, unlike a "br"

Any idea of the issue?
Your help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

If needed, this is the entire code of the countdown

```
<li class="limite">
Plus que <strong><font color="#ff0000">
<div id="clockdiv">
<span class="days"></span><div class="smalltext">jours</div>
<span class="hours"></span><div class="smalltext">hrs</div>
<span class="minutes"></span><div class="smalltext">mins</div>
<span class="seconds"></span><div class="smalltext">secs</div>
</font></strong> pour profiter de la promotion !
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t, 'days': days, 'hours': hours, 'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2);
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}
var timeInDays = 12;
var timeInMinutes = 4;
var timeInSeconds = 26;
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
if(document.cookie && document.cookie.match('myClock')){
  var deadline = document.cookie.match(/(^|;)myClock=([^;]+)/)[2];
}
else{
var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInDays*60*60*1000 + timeInMinutes*60*1000 +  timeInSeconds*1000);
  document.cookie = 'myClock=' + deadline + '; path=/; domain=. https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
}
</script>
</li>
```

Comment: A DIV is a block element, it stacks vertically by default. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements.

Answer (score 2):

A `<div>` element is a "block-level" element, meaning it always renders on its own line.

A `<span>` element is an "inline" element, meaning that it flows "inline" with the other content.

**To get what you want, you have two options:**

1. Change `<div class="smalltext">...</div>` to `<span
   class="smalltext">...</span>`
2. In your CSS `smalltext` class, add: `display:inline;`

Answer (score 1):

A div is a block-level element. You could do two things.

**1. Make the div an inline element.**

```
div {
display: inline;
}
```

**2. Make the whole one div.**

```
Plus que <strong><font color="#ff0000">
<div id="clockdiv">
    <div class="smalltext">
        <span class="days"></span>jours
        <span class="hours"></span>hrs
        <span class="minutes"></span>mins
        <span class="seconds"></span>secs
    </div>
</font></strong> pour profiter de la promotion !
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful here. That CSS will make **all <div> elements** flow as inline elements. Since the OP has isolated all the `<div>` elements in question with the CSS class `smalltext`, the selector should be: `div.smalltext`.

Answer (score 0):

div is a block element, so it will indeed force a new line.
Add some CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Be careful here. That CSS will make **all <div> elements** flow as inline elements. Since the OP has isolated all the `<div>` elements in question with the CSS class `smalltext`, the selector should be: `div.smalltext`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your div `float:left`

```css
.left{
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<li class="limite">
Plus que <strong><font color="#ff0000">
<div id="clockdiv">
<span class="days"></span><div class="smalltext left">jours</div>
<span class="hours"></span><div class="smalltext left">hrs</div>
<span class="minutes"></span><div class="smalltext left">mins</div>
<span class="seconds"></span><div class="smalltext left">secs</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `divs` if you have only flow content.

Answer (score 0):

By default, div is "display: block", which produces the line break. You could prevent line breaks by replacing div's by span's (which has "display: inline" by default).

Another option is change display property for div's you don't want line breaks, example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .no-ln-bk 
    { 
        display: inline 
    }
</style>

<div class="smalltext no-ln-bk">my text 1</div>
<div class="smalltext no-ln-bk">my text 2</div>
```

Comment: FYI `type="text/css"` hasn't been needed for several years now (since HTML5).